# Libphonenumber guess if number is possible

Tags: libphonenumber

It is possible to pass to libphonenumber only number without country format

> isNumberPossible(String phone)

For example I would like to check whether number is possible in international format. I don't want to pass local country code, because I don't it.

[This demo](https://rawgit.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo-compiled.html) forces me enter country

Answer (score 3):

In that demo, put in a phone number (e.g., +41 31 917 52 00) and then enter `US` for the country. The validation results are as follows:

```
****Validation Results:****
Result from isPossibleNumber(): true
Result from isValidNumber(): true
Result from isValidNumberForRegion(): false
Phone Number region: CH
Result from getNumberType(): FIXED_LINE
```

It returns true for isPossibleNumber, but false for isValidNumberForRegion. That sounds like it would work for your case. (I have the same case, so that's how I know.)

Comment: Interesting that without + symbol it says that phone number is not possble. Why ?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a number in international e164 format (with "+" sign), it doesn't require to enter a country code. If you don't write "+" it considers the number is in local format in some country so it needs to know the expected country, because numbering plans are different in different countries.